# Purging the cache of the requests library in Python?

Tags: python, caching, python-requests

I want to define a method that makes a simple web query against Wikipedia, and this is what I got:

```
def getPageHTML(page, language='en', project='wikipedia'):
    return requests.get('https://' + language + '.' + project + '.org/wiki/' + page).text
```

My problem is that when I ran this script last week as a part of a method that returns a certain date that I need, I was returned the correct output:

```
.../June 21, 2015
```

But I ran the script again today, and expected:

```
.../June 28, 2015
```

Instead I got again:

```
.../June 21, 2015
```

This seems like a simple caching error: is there any option or flag that I can set that will cause my request method to specifically *not* use the contents of the cache to fulfill a request?

If it is relevant, the specific page from which I am trying to read in content is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Resident_Mario/godate

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where you're pulling that date from, or with how Wikipedia structures its web pages, but just from looking at the webpage, it looks like it still says July 21 to me? Are you sure that the problem is actually with the requests library, and not just due to the webpage itself being out-of-date? (and as far as I'm aware, the requests library does not do any caching -- in fact, you need to actually download a [separate library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-cache) in order to make requests start caching).

Comment: The contents of the page for me at the moment are `BOF 2015-06-28 EOF`. But the script continues to return June 21! Something somewhere is not quite right.

Comment: Really? That's bizarre. I'm currently seeing `BOF 2015-06-21 EOF`

Comment: Hmm -- even more bizarrely, I tried checking on several different browsers, then tried checking on my phone. When I use Firefox and Chrome, I see 2015-06-21, but when I used my phone, I see 2015-06-28. Maybe it's some sort of caching issue that Wikipedia is having?

Comment: I see `BOF 2015-07-05 EOF` today. That said, @Michael0x2a is 100% correct. Requests does no caching by default. This is a problem with the server.